# Express: How to send multiple records to the view and access it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am developing an application in `Express` with `Mongo`. What I have to do is to read multiple `records` from `db` and send it to `view`. There I have to `render` those in `table`. This is, i have done so far:

my `router`:

```
router.route('/dashboard').get(function (req, res, next) {
    res.format({
        html: function () {
            mongoose.model('Register').find({'userid': req.session.email}, function (err, users) {
               var userMap={};
               users.forEach(function(user){
                  userMap[user._id]=user; 
               });
               res.json(userMap);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what I get in the view:
[image]

I want to render it in the view like this:

```
table
  tbody
    tr
      td #{user.pid}
      td #{user.sid}
      td #{user.rfname}
      td #{user.des}
```

I refered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103615/mongoose-get-full-list-of-users) but it doesn't tell how to access each `record` in the `view`? any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead try like this so you will have all the data into the user object res.json({user:userMap}); So that you can access it using the user object.So use the object to access elements like user[0].pid

```
router.route('/dashboard').get(function (req, res, next) {   
  mongoose.model('Register').find({'userid': req.session.email},function (err, users) { 
  var userMap={}; 
  users.forEach(function(user){ 
    userMap[user._id]=user; 
  });
  res.render('myviewname',{user:userMap});
  }); 
});
```

Comment: i tried it like you said with the same result... :(

Comment: can you post the complete json object view that you get?

Comment: Also you are sending an array object to view . So use the object to access elements  like user[0].pid,.. like looping.

Comment: i have posted that in the question, problem is, it does what is in the image above, rather i want it to access in the view.

Comment: router.route('/dashboard').get(function (req, res, next) {
    
            mongoose.model('Register').find({'userid': req.session.email}, function (err, users) {
               var userMap={};
               users.forEach(function(user){
                  userMap[user._id]=user; 
               });
               res.render('myviewname',{user:userMap});
            });

});

Comment: I have done this before and accessed the data like this `#{user.pid}` but it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace res.send() with res.json() so you get json object into view.

Comment: but how to access each `record` in `view`?

Comment: I did this and it returns json object but does not properly renders it in the view.

Comment: Can you post code snippet of what you get and exapmle how you want to display it?

Comment: Well there you have your data in object. All you have to go now is go trough each record and outup the data you want.

Comment: I know that, but how? because it does not render the table.

Comment: Can you post snippet where you render the view?

Comment: I have posted all of it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express generator or similar dir structure, you can pass the data from controller to view as an object and use a for-loop to iterate through each record and print in views. Check below example to get better idea :

routes/users.js (controller file)

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   const userData = await UserModel.find({}); // I'm using mongoose schema and model
   res.render('user', {userData: userData}); 
});
```

views/user.jade (view file)

```
table(border='1')
    tbody
    tr
        th First Name
        th Last Name
        th Email
        th Phone
    for user in userData
        tr
            td #{user.firstName}
            td #{user.lastName}
            td #{user.email}
            td #{user.phone}
```

This is my data :

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f9665e318ec5a064a7ae4ad"), "firstName" : "Anil", "lastName" : "Raj", "email" : "anil@gmail.com", "phone" : "7861171771", "password" : "123456" },                                                                                                                                                   { "_id" : ObjectId("5f966eb518ec5a064a7ae4ae"), "firstName" : "Arun", "lastName" : "Raj", "email" : "arun@gmail.com", "phone" : "7861171773", "password" : "123456" }]
```