# Return a list of mongoose error in a single response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently using Node.js, Mongoose and Express.js for backend development. This is a list of users I am trying to create using mongoose.

```
[
    {
        "username" : "abc",
        "password" : "123",
        "displayname" : "ABC",
        "email" : "test@example.com"
    },
    {
        "username" : "def",
        "password" : "123",
        "displayname" : "DEF",
        "email" : "test2@example.com"
    },
    {
        "username" : "ghi",
        "password" : "123",
        "displayname" : "GHI",
        "email" : "test@example.com"
    }
]
```

This is what I am currently doing on backend. I set username field as `unique` and mongoose will return error if one of usernames is already existed.

```
var lists = req.body;
lists.forEach(function(list) {      
    var user = new User();              
    user.username = list.username;
    user.email = list.email;
    user.displayname = list.displayname;
    user.password = hashed(list.password);
    user.save(function(err, user) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(list.username + ' is already registered.');
     }
    });
});
res.json({
    message: 'Users are successfully created'
});
```

I am trying to return a list of users already existed in database, but I can only do a list by `console.log` not in response json.

```
abc is already registered.
gef is already registered.
```

Is there any way to work on it? I couldn't save the value inside `user.save()` Thanks.

Comment: [Find all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103615/mongoose-get-full-list-of-users) and the return them. What's the big deal?

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in promise support instead of callbacks and this becomes trivial with `Promise.all`:

```
Promise.all(lists.map(list => { // .all waits for an array of promises.
    var user = new User();      // we `.map` which transforms every element of the array
    user.username = list.username;
    user.email = list.email;
    user.displayname = list.displayname;
    user.password = hashed(list.password);
    return user.save().then(x => null,e => `${list.username} already reistered`);
}).then(results => { // results of all save promises
    const errors = results.filter(Boolean); // we mapped successes to null in the `then`
    res.json(errors); // return all the errors
});
```